# insert rows in different order in oracle table

Tags: oracle, insert, oracle-data-integrator

I am using ODI 12c so the mission is to insert one plat file into one table Oracle

the file is like :

```
H030201707761133020171085009CA0126357320150506141438SL xxxx xxx xxx                         
***DEB062
09001SD
1003020171085009
....
...
..
.
.
.
0000010000001389600000013896               
509000002
199
***FIN062
```

I have one table 'A' which constitute one column 'COL' (lenght=250) where I want to save all my file's text (insert line by line). it save it  but not like in  my file order why !

it save it like

```
1003020171085009
xxxx
1003020171085009
....
...
..
***FIN062
.
H030201707761133020171085009CA0126357320150506141438SL xxxx xxx xxx
.               
509000002
199
0000010000001389600000013896
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We found a solution .If you are using ODI you need only put nothing in INSERT_HINT input text .let it empty like in picture below...And it will save your lines as they are in the plat file

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Rows in a table in a relational database do not have an 'order'. Unless you supply an ORDER BY clause with your SELECT statement the database is free to return the rows however it chooses. I suggest you add another column to your table, perhaps called LINE_NUMBER, in which you might store a "line number" value that you could use to order the rows from the table as you wish.

Best of luck.

### EDIT

If you really don't want to add a column to do the ordering of your data you can always embed a sequence number in the text of the `COL` column. For example, you could store the sequence number as the first 8 characters of the file, in a manner similar to the following:

```
DECLARE
  nLine_number  NUMBER;
  strLine       VARCHAR2(250);
  f             UTL_FILE.FILE_TYPE;
BEGIN
  f := UTL_FILE.FOPEN('dir', 'file', 'r');

  SELECT COUNT(*)
    INTO nLine_number
    FROM A;

  BEGIN
    WHILE TRUE THEN
      UTL_FILE.GET_LINE(f, strLine, 242);  -- 8 less than size of A.COL

      -- Insert new line into A.COL

      nLine_number := nLine_number + 1;

      INSERT INTO A(COL)
        VALUES (TO_CHAR(nLine_number, '00000000') || strLine);
    LOOP;
  EXCEPTION
    WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN
      UTL_FILE.FCLOSE(f);
  END;
EXCEPTION
  WHEN OTHERS THEN
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Error: ' || SQLERRM);
    UTL_FILE.FCLOSE_ALL;
    RAISE;
END;
```

Then when you want to read through `A` in the order the lines were added to the table you can do:

```
SELECT SUBSTR(COL, 9)
  FROM A
  ORDER BY TO_NUMBER(SUBSTR(COL, 1, 8);
```

Not pretty, but it avoids having to add a `LINE_NUMBER` column to `A`.

Comment: there is any solution without add a LINE_NUMBER column

Comment: I added an example of how to do this without adding a LINE_NUMBER column.

Comment: first thanks for your answer. Although I added another column (LINE_NUMBER) and make a sequence which increment by 1 as its value. it doesn't change anything. it's keeping insert them with no order